# Multiple domains with same URIs but different proxy_pass in NginX

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a nginx instance which is responsible for handling both production and pre-production domains (domain.com and pre.domain.com).

Currently I have separate 'server' block for both domains. However, content of those block is the almost the same - same URIs but proxied to different backend servers. I would like to have more clear nginx configuration so I thought about putting domains in same 'server' block and make a proxy based on domain.

Unfortunately example below seems not to work:

```
server_name pre.domain.com domain.com;
location /someuri {
        if ($host = 'pre'domain.com') {
        proxy_pass  http://pre.backend/someuri;
        }
        proxy_pass  http://backend/someuri;
}
```

Unfortunately my idea failed because of following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:17
```

I also tried to play with 'map' but result is the same.

The question is: is there a possibility to handle multiple domains in one 'server' block and get content from different upstreams for 'same' URIs?

Thanks in advance for a tip.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `/someuri` off the end of the `proxy_pass` (assuming it is the same as the location) as no transformation is actually necessary. Have you read [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)?

Comment: Thanks, I need to check if this approach will work with all backend servers.
I saw this article regarding 'if' in nginx several times but to be honest right now I do not see better solution than use this statement when I want to keep everything in one 'server' block.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate servers configuration and avoid "if" directive. You can keep equal configuration for all servers in the include files.

```
server {
server_name domain.com;
location /someuri {
   proxy_pass  http://backend/someuri;
}
include domain.com.cfg;
}

server {
server_name pre.domain.com;
location /someuri {
   proxy_pass  http://pre.backend/someuri;
}
include domain.com.cfg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not solve my problem. I have ~50 'locations' directive which proxies to different backend servers. Part, which is exactly the same for both domains is already included from separate configuration files.